# New questions indicator for watched tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters, tag-watching

There is a red indicator in the CQL (I tried to reproduce one in the screenshot below) that shows up when new questions matching the filter are available.

There isn't such thing for *watched* tags and I have to manually click on each of them to check if new questions came in since my last visit. (I know life can be tough sometimes ;)

**Would it be possible to have such an indicator for watched tags?**

[image]

Comment: Why not make filters for each tag?

Comment: @Laurel I suppose I could but it seems like an obvious feature for something called _Watched Tags_. Otherwise it's just a static list of bookmarks really. If it can be done for filters which are in general more involved than a simple tag, it should be feasible for just one tag. I may be wrong of course.